# Python doctest: Skip entire block?

Tags: python, doctest

I've got a Python module with docstrings in class methods, and a real-world example in the module docstring. The distinction is that the method-docstrings have been carefully crafted to be utterly repeatable tests, while the real-world example is just a copy'n'paste of the history from a Linux shell - which happened to invoke the python interpreter.

E.g.

```
"""
Real-world example:

# python2.5
Python 2.5 (release25-maint, Jul 20 2008, 20:47:25)
[GCC 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from packagename import module
>>> module.show_real_world_usage()
'Hello world!'
"""

class SomeClass(object):
    def someMethod(self):
        """
        >>> 1 == 1
        True
        """
```

I want to run the doctest in `SomeClass.someMethod`, but not in the module's docstrings.

Doctest's `+SKIP` directive only works per line, which would mean adding 10s of lines to my real-world example. Ugly!

Is there a way to make doctest skip an entire block? A bit like `<!-- ... -->` in HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution has been to trim the the 3-character `>>>` and `...` leaders where I want doctest to skip over them, making them 2-characters.

So

```
"""
>>> from packagename import module
>>> module.show_real_world_usage()
'Hello world!'
"""
```

has become

```
"""
>> from packagename import module
>> module.show_real_world_usage()
'Hello world!'
"""
```

Epydoc doesn't display this as nicely as it does doctests, but I can live with this. A skip-until-further-notice directive in doctest would be welcome though.

Comment: A workaround regarding the display can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55002297/5350621

Comment: The examples cannot be copy-pasted into an IPython REPL and work, afterwards.

Comment: this won't play nice with searches. No doubt other workflows too

Answer (score 26):

Wrap the example in a function and then skip the function call:

```
"""
>>> def example():
...    from packagename import module
...    module.show_real_world_usage()
...
>>> example() # doctest: +SKIP
'Hello world!'
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's not an actual doctest by any means, you can just assign the value to a variable.   For example,

```
example_usage = """
Real-world example:

# python2.5
...
"""
```

will cause that "test" to not be evaluated.

It might be better to use `__example_usage__` (or something else surrounded by double-underscores) so that it's clear that's a "magic" variable and not a variable to be used within the context of the script.

Comment: Neat, but then it's also invisible to help() and epydoc.

Comment: I'm not sure about `help()`, but you can just add a new field in epydoc: http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epydoc.html#adding-new-fields

Comment: [Dunder names should be reserved for system-defined names.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers). I would make it a simple private instead: `_example_usage`

Answer (score 2):

A small workaround building upon [RobM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1809516/5350621) preserves the display/formatting by starting the example with a >>> like that:

```
""" 
>>>
>> from packagename import module 
>> module.show_real_world_usage() 
'Hello world!' 
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

I went for the `# doctest: +SKIP` on every line

```
def doc_test_test():
    """Doc tests
    
    Examples:
        
        >>> do_something1() # doctest: +SKIP
        >>> do_something2() # doctest: +SKIP
        >>> do_something3() # doctest: +SKIP
    """
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

with [`xdoctest`](https://xdoctest.readthedocs.io/) you can use this `>>> # doctest: +SKIP` as first line:

```
def some_function():
    """
    Some documentation
    
    Examples:
        
        >>> # doctest: +SKIP
        >>> do_something() 
        >>> do_something_else()
        >>> and_do_this()
    """
```

unfortunately `doctest` itself crashes (and sphinx prints that as `>>>` instead of completely ignoring it).